# SQL Alchemy Error when moving colums to init method

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is my User object that I'm using to write to MySQL using SQLAlchemy

```
class User(Base):

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        self.first_name = Column(String)
        self.last_name = Column(String)
        self.email_id = Column(String)
        self.mobile = Column(String)
        self.username = Column(String)
        self.hashed_password = Column(String)

    def set_first_name(self, first_name):
        self.first_name = first_name

    def set_last_name(self, last_name):
        self.last_name = last_name

    def set_email_id(self, email):
        self.email_id = email

    def set_mobile(self, mobile):
        self.mobile = mobile

    def set_username(self, username):
        self.username = username

    def set_hashed_password(self, password):
        self.hashed_password = password

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(id=%d, first_name=%s, last_name=%s, email_id=%s, mobile=%s, username=%s)>"%(self.id, self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email_id, self.mobile, self.username)
```

When I run the program, this is what I get the following error,

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|User|user could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'user'
```

This code works if I take the attribute definitions out of the init and remove the self prefix. Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy's declarative base mechanism establishes a Python metaclass.  That means that SQLAlchemy will specially process the definition of your class.
The purpose of that processing is to construct an `sqlalchemy.orm.Mapper` for each mapped class.  That mapper represents the mapping between your database tables and your class.
In order to do that, SQLAlchemy generally needs to be able to find a primary key.  This is required in order to define the identity associated with each mapped instance, so that mapped objects can be cached/found in sessions.  That at least needs to be possible when your mapped class is constructed.
That means that you need to define the column of at least the primary key on the class.
Other answers have explained that much, although I think I've provided a bit more detail.

There is a more fundamental problem though.

```
id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
```

is of course a call to the Column function you import from SQLAlchemy.  However, the return from the `Column` function is a schema item. This schema item is converted by declarative base into a descriptor similar to the kind of descriptor that the `property` decorator gives you.  Such descriptors only work on a class, not an instance of that class.

Let's say I have a class mapped to a table called `User` and an instance of that user in a variable `bob`.

```
User.id
```

Is a description of the identity column.  However

```
bob.id
```

is the number that identifies Bob in the users table.
That is, columns aren't intended to be assigned to members of self, they are intended to be assigned to classes.

So:

- You need to have at least the primary key column on your class when you define it.
- It's generally a good idea to have all your Columns there.
- You can add a `Column` definition to your class later, although things will only work if you arrange for that column to get into your table
- It's always wrong to add a `Column` to an instance of a mapped class.  `self.x = Column` is always wrong.

Comment: "However, the return from the Column function is a descriptor" is not quite exactly true. A `Column` instance is not a descriptor, but an `InstrumentedAttribute`, which Declarative replaces the columns with during class construction, is.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä  It looks like the return of Column itself is a schema item.  I actually don't think it's an instrumented attribute: I think that terminology is used within the ORM and particularly mapper, so I'd be quite surprised to see that in base sqlalchemy.  It's not a descriptor though; answer updated.  Thanks.

Comment: No it is not, and I did not mean to say it is. Reading it now I see that I worded that sentence extremely poorly. The point was: during class construction Declarative builds a `Table` instance to map the class to, moves the `Column` instances there and replaces the class attributes with `InstrumentedAttribute` instances, which act as descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLAlchemy ORM (almost) always requires a primary key. You have indeed defined one inside your `__init__()` function. The problem is that `__init__()` doesn't get called until you create a `User` object. I assume you create your database before a `User` object ever gets created. Thus as far as the SQLAlchemy ORM is concerned, a primary key does not exist for `User` (nor any of the other attributes declared inside `__init__`).

The solution, as I think you already found from your last line, is to declare them as class attributes where as soon you do something like `from models import User` the attributes are defined and SQLAlchemy can properly build your `User` table.

```
class User(Base):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    email_id = Column(String)
    mobile = Column(String)
    username = Column(String)
    hashed_password = Column(String)

    def set_first_name(self, first_name):
        self.first_name = first_name

    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to declare the column definitions inside the `__init__()` function. Change your class definition to something like this and it should work:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    email_id = Column(String)
    mobile = Column(String)
    username = Column(String)
    hashed_password = Column(String)
```

Comment: This answer does not attempt to answer the question.  The OP explained that it works if you do as described, but asked why that's the case.  You made no attempt to answer why.