# How am I not overwriting a variable in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Currently working through a tutorial for Flask Python, right now it's giving a basic tutorial on databases using SQLAlchemy. I'm trying to code along with the project, so far my code is working as it's supposed to, but I'm a bit confused why a certain section works the way it does.

Below is the the snippet that I'm struggling to grasp, it's using the SQLAlchemy python library to build a class that represents a database table.

```
class Puppy(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'puppies'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    breed = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.breed = breed
```

I'm able to then in a separate python script import the 'Puppy' object and create a table entry for new puppies via calling the Puppy object and passing in the appropriate parameters, for example:

```
Puppy('Fido','4','border collie')
```

Where I'm getting lost is at the variable assignment. Before the init method is run all these variables are assigned SQLAlchemy Column objects, but whenever a Puppy object is instantiated I would have thought whatever is assigned to those variables would get overwritten. It seems like the init method should pass parameters to the column objects, not assign them inputs, but somehow this is how it works. Any clarification would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Here are some pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521700/sql-alchemy-error-when-moving-colums-to-init-method/47522223#47522223. The behaviour is based on metaclass and descriptors.